# Which one is true?

Tags: grammar

While writing an email I was confused about using *none.* Which one is true among the given options?

- > none of the claims satisfy the admission

or

- > none claims satisfy the admission

Comment: Please include more context, or provide us with the source. Or are you just checking which among this is correct?

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us more about this sentence. Which example do _you_ think is correct, and why? Can you tell us what research you did to learn about the use of _none?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first sentence is correct. Please observe the general structure:

> [none] [of the + noun]
>
> [all] [of the + noun]
>
> [some] [of the + noun]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that a little more information on the context of these sentences would be helpful.
 However from what you have provided so far, your first sentence sounds more natural.